# Uncaught ReferenceError: Bind_ChainHotel is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I've defined a function named Bind_ChainHotel in javascript on the Change of dropdown selection, i fill data into another dropdown through ajax. I am using HtmlHelper.DropDownList in MVC5. Whenever i select any option i got this error in console.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlShellLevel", new List<SelectListItem>
                                                    {
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Chain",Value= "1"},
                                                        new SelectListItem{Text="Hotel",Value= "2"}
                                                    }, "Select Level", new { onchange = "Bind_ChainHotel(this.value);", @class = "form-control" })
```

**Javascript**

```
(function Bind_ChainHotel(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Bind_ChainHotel", "Shell")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { "id": id },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ddlChain_Hotel").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, chain_hotel) {
                $("#ddlChain_Hotel").append('<option value="' + chain_hotel.Value + '">' +
                     chain_hotel.Text + '</option>');
            });
            if (id == 1) {
                $('#lblChainHotel').text('Select Chain');
                $("#ddlChain_Hotel").prepend('<option value="0">Select Chain</option>');
            }
            else {
                $("#lblChainHotel").text("Select Hotel");
                $("#ddlChain_Hotel").prepend('<option value="0">Select Hotel</option>');
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading and ending parenthesis

```
function Bind_ChainHotel(id) {
  $.ajax({
    .....
  });
};
```

Comment: As I said in the answer, remove the leading `(` before `function` and the final `)()` at the end (and make sure your script is at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `document.ready`

Answer (score 1):

**Stephen Muecke**'s answer is right, but he can't be bothered to explain, so I will do.

You **define** a function as follows, note it's defined and stored, **not executed**.

```
function Bind_ChainHotel(id) { /* do something with id */ }
```

Now you can **invoke** that function by its name, when you add parentheses `()` to name. Since the function is stored you can do that whereever and how often you need:

```
Bind_ChainHotel("myId"); // with this invocation function is executed
```

In your code you do both **define and execute** together, function is defined inside parentheses and then immediately executed caused by the second parentheses added at the end:

```
(function Bind_ChainHotel(id) { /* do something with id */ }) ();
```

This is called an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). The function is **not stored**, after one execution it's gone, you can't invoke it any more.

There's another not error but point worth to note: You write multiple times `$("#ddlChain_Hotel")`, and each time a new jQuery object with same content is created. That's much to write and takes much time to execute. Create one object and store it in a variable, then reference to the var by it's name.

```
// wrap the code in a $(document).ready to ensure that all DOM elements are there at runtime
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ddlChain = $("#ddlChain_Hotel"),
        lblChain = $('#lblChainHotel');

    function Bind_ChainHotel(id) {
        $.ajax({
            /* ... */
            success: function(data) {
                ddlChain.empty(); // var ddlChain holds $("#ddlChain_Hotel")
                /* ... */
            }
        });
    }
});
```